# Why empty fields in Rsyslog?

Tags: logging, rsyslog

In our Rsyslog database, we are using rsyslog version 5.8.6, we have so many empty fields for some columns, for example, EventBinaryData, EventSource, EventUser, EventCategory, all these fields are empty.

And there are many fields are 0s, for example, MaxAvailable, CurrUsage, MinUsage, MaxUsage.

I have walked through the Rsyslog homepage, and tried to find the answers, but I didn't get the answers. I think it's probably a configuration issue, but I am not sure. Can anyone help me on below questions or show any hint on these?

Why there are many empty fields there?
How do we put information there to make them not empty or make them useful?

Comment: Can you confirm that the syslog server on the sending side is forwarding data for those fields? If it's not sent by the client, the server won't make something up.